# Grails save method, doesn't recall method correctly if has error

Tags: grails, gsp

I have those two method for create a new domain:

First one is a modified **create()** method, instead of respond only the subDomain created with the parameters in the form (inside newSubDomain view), it also pass the userDomainList to the gsp so i can create a select from it.

```
def newSubDomain() {
        def currentUser = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser() 
        def domainList = currentUser.domains //an hasMany domain for user
        def subDomain = new SubDomain(params)
        [subDomain: subDomain, domainList: domainList ] 
    }
```

Second one is the **save()** method

```
def saveSubDomain(SubDomain subDomain) {

    if (subDomain== null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (subDomain.hasErrors()) {
        respond subDomain.errors, view:'newSubDomain'
        return
    }

    subDomain.save flush: true    

    redirect(controller: "controller", action: "action")               
}
```

SubDomain must have a unique name, if i create a SubDomain with the same name, i want it to show the error message on top of newSubDomain view, this happens, but when he recall the method passing the error, it doenst reload and/or pass the "domainList" so he cannot load the select inside the view.

This is part of the code of the **newSubDomain.gsp** view

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${this.subDomain}">
        <ul class="errors" role="alert">
            <g:eachError bean="${this.subDomain}" var="error">
                <li <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}"/></li>
            </g:eachError>
        </ul>
    </g:hasErrors>


    <g:form controller="subDomain " action="saveSubDomain">

        <f:field bean="subDomain " property="name"/>
        <br>
        <f:field bean="subDomain" property="domain">
        <g:select name="domain"
                  from="${domainList}"
                  optionKey="id"
                  optionValue="name"
        />
    </f:field>

        <g:actionSubmit value="Save sub Domain" action="saveSubDomain"/>
    </g:form>
```

What I'm doing wrong? I dont know much about grails (or web applications in general) there's a better way to pass parameters to view from controllers? Why when i call the newSubDomain view again when it encounter an error doesn't pass the domainList?

Answer (score 0):

In newSubDomain, you marshal the data for the domainList, and provide a new subDomain to the newSubDomain view for its use.

In saveSubDomain, that method receives ONLY the subdomain object. When errors are found, the saveSubDomain controller method uses the data it has to send the user back to the newSubDomain view -- but the saveSubDomain method does not have a  populated domainList variable.  So the view has no domainList data to show.